# Angular ng-option custom filter multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a project requiring that I build an angular menu with multiple drop down filters. As the end user selects one filter the other two filters update accordingly. I already learned the hard way not to use the ng-repeat with options and now for the life of me cannot figure out how to get my select fields in the view to reflect changes that will be caused by events in the view.

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="large-8 columns" ng-controller="democontroller"  >
      <label> Demographic
        <select ng-options = "x.demo as x.demo for x in groups | filteredDemo" ng-model = "demoValue">
          <option value="">Please Select A Group</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label> Location
        <select  ng-model = "locationValue" ng-options = "x.location as x.location for x in groups ">
          <option value="">Please Select A Location</option>
        </select>
      </label>
       <label> Days
         <select  ng-model = "dayValue" ng-options = "x.days as x.days for x in groups " >
           <option value="">Please Select A Meeting Day</option>
         </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
      <p>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my current javascript:

```
var app=angular.module('selectapp',[]);


app.controller('democontroller',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("jsoninfo.php").success(function(response){$scope.groups=response;});

$scope.currentValues = ['1','0','0'];

app.filter('filteredDemo', function(){

return function(e){
    if(e == 1){
        return e;
    }
}

});

}]);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain the *howto* with two levels (*group* and *location*). Adding levels should be obvious after that.

- `ng-model` value of the first select list will hold the `selectedGroup`
- `ng-model` value of the second select list will hold the `selectedLocation`

In `ng-options`, We must select the full object, but we will diplay only the name. Thus we will have `ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups"`. We select the full object because in the dependent dropdown, we will iterate over the nested collection, here `selectedGroup.locations`

```
    <label>Demographic
        <select ng-model="selectedGroup" ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups">
            <option value="">Please Select A Group</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>Location
        <select ng-model="selectedLocation" ng-options="location as location.name for location in selectedGroup.locations">
            <option value="">Please Select A Location</option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

Here is a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjzftt95/)** I've made with dummy data.

Comment: Is it possible to allow the user to user to select inputs independent of one another as this still forces a procedural input ie step one then two. Also my json array is a singular return as follows:   {
name: "7",
locations: "1",
day: "6"
},
{
name: "3",
locations: "1",
day: "4"
},
{
name: "7",
locations: "1",
day: "2"
},
{
name: "7",
locations: "1",
day: "3"
},

Comment: What should be the values for the "days" dropdown? `['6', '4', '2'] ?` And the different values for the "group" dropdown `['7', '3', '7'] ?`